# CAS doesn't return any XML when a ticket is validated

Tags: xml, validation, server, cas

i currently have a CAS server in https://localhost:8443/cas/login, also i have a newsletter manager in http://localhost/lists/admin/, i'm trying to log in the newsletter manager using CAS but when i validate the ticket CAS returns an empty XML

When i run URL: "localhost:8443/cas/p3/serviceValidate?service=localhost/lists/admin&ticket=ST-3-jkeTR07aOvA2w1resaYA-localhost" in a browser instead get a XML i return to the login screen

Comment: please put your tomcat logs after run validating URL....

Comment: i'm sorry, i totally forget about this. I was able to solve it. I don't know why but i wasn't able to acess the main control panel to allow the Service use CAS so i modify "deployerConfigContext.xml" and add the service manually